# FROM_UNIXTIME() works on MySQLWorkbench but returns null for PHP client

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have tried running a simple select query through MySQLWorkbench as well as through a query from PHP web app with different results:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(created_at) FROM test_tbl;
```

Through MySQLWorkbench I get the correctly formatted date and time. But selecting from PHP I get null.

The PHP query is fine and returns all other columns in the table perfectly (the above query is shortened massively) so am thinking maybe its something to do with client timezone that may be selecting null?

Comment: show your php code

Comment: Two options:  (1) `created_at` is `NULL` in some columns; (2) you are processing the returned value incorrectly in PHP.  Probably the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. So bit of an odd one, I added an AS to the query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(created_at) AS created_at FROM test_tbl;
```

and it returned properly in PHP. This worked no matter what I returned it AS, just as long as I returned it AS something.